# How to update a status label while processing something on the server?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanel

I have a requirement to process (server side) a lot of data (files) when the user clicks a button. I'd like to show a running summary of each file name as it's being processed. I've been trying to do it with the UpdatePanel control but only the very last update happens. Here's some simple code I created to simulate the issue (it should count up from 1 to 10 but instead waits the 5 seconds and outputs 10):

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script runat="server">
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(Button1);
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
            {
                Label1.Text = i.ToString();
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
                UpdatePanel1.Update();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there a way to make this work? Or maybe a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance,
Jason

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use an ajax call to the server. I have copied this code from one of my previous projects it's a bit long code. try it and let me know if it works.

**page1.aspx**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function BeginProcess() {
            // Create an iframe.
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

            // Point the iframe to the location of
            //  the long running process.
            iframe.src = "Process.aspx";

            // Make the iframe invisible.
            iframe.style.display = "none";

            // Add the iframe to the DOM.  The process
            //  will begin execution at this point.
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);

            // Disable the button and blur it.
             document.getElementById('trigger').blur();
        }

        function UpdateProgress(PercentComplete, Message) {
            document.getElementById('ContentPlaceHolder2_lbDownload').setAttribute("disabled", "true");
            document.getElementById('trigger').value = PercentComplete + '%: ' + Message;

        }


  </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" Runat="Server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>

    <input type="submit" value="Start BackUp Process!" 
    id="trigger" onclick="BeginProcess(); return false;"
    style="width: 250px;" />

    </ContentTemplate>
   </asp:UpdatePanel>


     <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" 
     AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ProgressTemplate>  
         </ProgressTemplate> 
</asp:UpdateProgress>


</asp:Content>
```

**Process.aspx.cs**

```
public partial class Process : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
        // Padding to circumvent IE's buffer.
        Response.Write(new string('*', 256));
        Response.Flush();

        // Initialization
        UpdateProgress(0, "Initializing task.");


        try
        {


            foreach (yourloophere)
            {

                        UpdateProgress(increment, db.Name + " Backup Started....");
                //your process code
                        UpdateProgress(increment, db.Name + " Backup Completed!");
  //your process code
                        SB.Append(db.Name + "BackUp Complted!");

        //your process code
                SB.Append("<br/>");



            }


            // All finished!
            UpdateProgress(100, "All Database BackUp Completed!");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            UpdateProgress(0, "Exception: " + ex.Message);

            SB.Append("Back Up Failed!");
            SB.Append("<br/>");
            SB.Append("Failed DataBase: " + DBName);
            SB.Append("<br/>");
            SB.Append("Exception: " + ex.Message);

        }


    }


    protected void UpdateProgress(double PercentComplete, string Message)
    {
        // Write out the parent script callback.
        Response.Write(String.Format("<script type=\"text/javascript\">parent.UpdateProgress({0}, '{1}');</script>", PercentComplete, Message));
        // To be sure the response isn't buffered on the server.    
        Response.Flush();
    }


}
```

Comment: Wow, this is definitely more complicated than I was hoping for. Since this is functionality I was only going to use once then throw away (migrating data from old system to new) I've decided not to worry about it for now. Thanks for the answer though, could come in handy in the future.